# How to attach an artifact with assembly-plugin during custom lifecycle

Tags: maven-2, plugins, maven, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin

i'm trying to create a plugin with a custom lifecycle :

```
/**
 * @goal my-goal
 * @execute lifecycle="my-custom-lifecycle" phase="attach-foo"
 */
public class MyMojo extends AbstractMojo {
...
```

with src/main/resources/META-INF/maven/lifecycle.xml file :

```
<lifecycles>
  <lifecycle>
    <id>attach-foo</id>
    <phases>
      <phase>
        <id>package</id>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>
                org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:single
              </goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <descriptorRefs>
                  <descriptor>adescriptor.xml</descriptor>
              </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </phase>
    </phases>
  </lifecycle>
</lifecycles>
```

Assembly-plugin is called unfortunately the zip artifact generated is not attached and install in repo...

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Which version of the maven-assembly-plugin was used?  Per the [plugin docs](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/single-mojo.html), there is an optional parameter `attach` available in versions 2.2-beta-1 and later.  The value defaults to `true` meaning the created artifact should end up in the repository.